# Polish characters not display in PySpark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, encoding, polish

I am using PySpark on Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.6 and Spark 3.3.
When I am trying to display some polish characters i obtain "?" instead of them.
Here is the sample of my code and output:

`print(f"Średnia ilość wynosi: {my_avg}")`

output:

`?rednia ilo?? wynosi: 2.5280988358080707`

My encoding is utf-8.

Comment: "My encoding is utf-8." what does this mean? What encoding?

Comment: In any case, I suspect this is an issue with your jupyter notebook, so I'd guess this has something to do with the jupyter kernel configuration

Comment: My global encoding. I dont know if it matters. sys.getdefaultencoding() gives me utf-8

Comment: That isn't really relevant. Is that what you mean by "global encoding?" What does `sys.stdout.encoding` give you?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean. Printing sys.stdout.encoding gives me None

Comment: Ah, I bet it's because `sys.stdout.isatty()` is `False`. Look, this is almost certainly an issue with Jupyter. You need to provide more details about your setup.